# how to set data to element dynamically in loop using $.data

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-in-loop

I am setting data to elements dynamically in loop, the sets successfully, but when I get it back it shows me the data of last element.
Here is the code:

```
var i = 1;
for (a in data.data) {
  var obj = $.extend(options.add.start, data.data[a], options.add.end),
  tr = '';
  tr += `<tr class="table-row index-${i}" id="index-${i}">`;
  tr += `<td><div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="row-checkbox" name="ids[]" value="${data.data[a].id}"></div></td>`;
  for (b in obj) {
    if (b !== 'id') {
      if (typeof options[b] === 'function') {
        tr += `<td>${options[b](obj)}</td>`;
      } else {
        tr += `<td>${obj[b]}</td>`;
      }
    }
  }
  tr += `</tr>`;

  $(options.table).find('tbody').append(tr);
  var jqTr = $(options.table).find('tbody').find('.index-' + i);
  jqTr.data('row', obj);
  i++;
}
```

It sets successfully, but when I access it, it gives me last item data.

Comment: how is i getting replaced with value in `id="index-${i}"` and how is this selector matches with partial classname `find('.index-' + i);` ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 i is unique in every tr.
i append a tr to tbody and then get last one from table and assign data to that tr.
is there i m doing wrong?